# Advice on persistant data type to use

Tags: ios, xcode, persistence

Newbie question - I would like some advice on the best persistant data type to use.

Requirements:

1. Data to be stored : Simple text and pictures
2. App Type: Information app featuring drill down tables and detailed view screens with several images on screen.
3. Data Updates: Yes, the app will be updated on a regular basis with new text and images, (updates preferable downloaded in the background, whilst the app is running and this data will be stored)

Can anybody offer me some advise as to the best persistant data type to use to.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Choose SQlite database. You can store text and pictures there.

Comment: Thanks Maxium for the reply.  Since I need to download and save all images from a website, is SQlite DB the best choice for doing this?

Comment: Mate it really doesn't matter how do you get these images. :)